# Curl under rotation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Consider $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ smooth. Let $R$ be a rotation matrix.

> There holds, for $g(y)=Rf(R^t y)$, that $R^t (\nabla_y \times g) (y) = (\nabla_x \times f )(R^t y )$

I was able to show this using the "circulation" definition, see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)#Definition). Would you have other ways to see it, e.g. without using line integrals?

Comment: You might also be able to use the fact that curl corresponds to $d : \Omega^1 \to \Omega^2$, which gives a coordinate-free description of something very closely related to the curl; and then, you would just need to check that $R$ interacts well with the correspondence of $\Omega^1$ and $\Omega^2$ with vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Could you please clarify what are $d$, $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$? @DanielSchepler

Comment: The Wikipedia article you linked to has a section on "differential forms" and the relation of curl to $d$ which is the exterior derivative from 1-forms to 2-forms.